# I need to write a query by inputting multiple values. Trying to find best way to achieve this

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have big list of aliases (around 90) which I want to input into query to get other data. Below is my query with three values. If I do for all 90 it will be big query and this may not be the right way to do. Is there a simple way I can make this work? Alias is nvarchar(25)

```
Select a.Description, a.Cost, a.ItemID, a.Alias
From Item a
and (a.alias like '72324612176%'
or a.alias like '74504200010%'
or a.alias like '76615027006%')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did this work for the whole block of aliases? We're not really a script writing service, so it would be best if you tried this and then reported how it worked, or where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your list of aliases stored in a table, you can do a join to that table. e.g.

```
SELECT
    a.Description
    ,a.Cost
    ,a.ItemID
    ,a.Alias
FROM
    Item a
    JOIN Aliases al ON a.Alias LIKE al.Alias + '%'
```